# Software for landscape design?

Tags: drawing, mapping, landscape, gardening

I am looking for software for landscape design. I'd like to be able to easily draw buildings, fences, parking areas, as well as represent trees, bushes, gardens etc.

A free cross platform or web based option is optimal, OS is not important to me. I don't need tons of features, as I am no pro, but extra features are nice.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an online tool that allows you to build and design garden/landscaping layouts:

[Garden Planner 3](http://smallblueprinter.com/garden/planner.html) (Online Demo, Downloadable Trial, $24, Windows/OS X)

[image: Screenshot of Garden Planner 3]

It provides you with a straight-forward GUI to quickly design a landscape. I haven't used it other than play with the online demo for a few minutes, but it looks promising enough.